# ASP.NET C# CRUD dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialog, crud

Sorry if this has been answered but I can't find it. I'm brand new to c#, ASP.net, entity framework and visual studio (coming from JS + rails). I need to do the following:

1. Click on member section title should open member add dialog
2. Right click on each member should open context menu with two options: edit and delete
3. Edit option should open same dialog as add new dialog with pre-populated data.

I've done plenty of CRUD work in JS and rails, pre populated edit forms are familiar, but not a dialog box isn't at all.

If yall can just give me quick examples or point me in the right direction (besides the obv documentation (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETMessageBox-3e8c6273) it would be greatly appreciated! For someone brand new to this whole thing I find these tutorials kind of bewildering.

Comment: Examples and right directions are available in tons on Google. Look for JQuery modal dialogs in Google. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can see a tutorial here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-in-asp-net-mvc-using-ajax-and-bootstrap/

Keyword for searching: ASP.NET Ajax with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [scaffolding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_scaffolding.htm).

But after you would need to change routing and click events to show what you need in modal window.